# How to find out, is a logged in user having view all or modify all permission

Tags: apex

How can I get in my service class(Apex class) that a logged in user is having **view all and modify all** permissions on any particular object.

Comment: i want to see how to identify if user has modify all/view all permission from code

Comment: Can you give a bit more context to the question, i.e. what is the use case. Also, have you looked into the with sharing and without sharing keywords. If not, check it out here https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the permissionsetassignment object to determine if a user has PermissionsViewAllData or PermissionsModifyAllData (I believe, check the documentation). See https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm for more information.

Edit: You can also query for specific objects. The items mentioned above are the global permissions.

Comment: Can we query ObjectPermissions object instead?

Comment: @rahulgawale if you want the permissions for a specific object, yes.